# Fedora no permission to user home in mount

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, mount, fedora

I created a user to use for backups with FTP. I moved the home directory to a mounted drive and gave the user permission to `rwx` using ACLs. User has a shell, user has a password but when I log into the server using the user through SSH. I get the following error.

```
Could not chdir to home directory /mnt/NAS/nextcloud_data/linuxman/files/PUSCraft/Backups: Permission denied
-bash: /mnt/NAS/nextcloud_data/linuxman/files/PUSCraft/Backups/.bash_profile: Permission denied
```

Folder permissions are as follows:

```
drwxrws---+  6 mcbackup mcbackup       4096 Jul 12  2020  Backups
```

And this is the ACL configuration:

```
# file: Backups
# owner: mcbackup
# group: mcbackup
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
user:linuxman:rwx
user:mcbackup:rwx
user:1002:---
user:1003:---
user:1004:---
user:1005:rwx
user:1006:---
group::rw-
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:linuxman:rwx
default:user:mcbackup:rwx
default:user:1002:---
default:user:1003:---
default:user:1004:---
default:user:1005:rwx
default:user:1006:---
default:group::rw-
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

I don't know much SELinux but I did not see any booleans that may cause issues, to my knowledge.

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

**Update**: Forgot to mention, the user in question is `mcbackup`.

**Update 1**: I looked at the SELinux contexts and stuff of the default home directories and added it to mcbackup's home folder

```
sudo chcon -r user_home_dir_t Backups
```

Still getting the same permission error when logging into SSH.

Comment: Can you try to set SELINUX=permissive in /etc/sysconfig/selinux and reboot ?

Comment: Does the mcbackup user have read and execute permission to the various enclosing folders (mnt, NAS, nextcloud_data, linuxman, files, and PUSCraft)?

Comment: @Gordon the only directory it doesn't not have those permissions to is /mnt, but everything else it does. was not sure if i should do that to a root directory or not but I'll give it a try when I can

Comment: @On4r4p i tried using a directory /mcbackup as a test and that worked just fine. so i think selinux is ruled out as an issue.

Comment: What are the permissions on /mnt? I'd expect everyone to have read and execute to that; of not, that's likely the problem.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Your comment fixed my problem. I added an acl for mcbackup to /mnt and all the subfolders that led to the users home and it is working now :) - Strange, i did not need to do that in ubuntu the last time i did something identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I order to access files in a given directory, you need the appropriate access to the individual file(s) (read and/or write, depending on what you're doing with them), and also at least execute (aka "search") access to the directory *and all of the directories on the path to it*. If you don't have at least execute access to a particular directory, you can't touch anything within it (including subdirectories). (Note: you need read access to list the contents of a directory, but if you already know the name of the item you want, that's not strictly needed.)

In this case, it looks like the problem was missing access to the /mnt directory (and therefore everything inside it). This is rather unusual; I'm used to /mnt having read and execute allowed for everyone, something like this:

```
$ ls -ld /mnt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 25  2019 /mnt
```

...but if you want it locked down for some reason, granting access via an ACL will do the trick.